# Error in HIbernate Querying Language

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, netbeans

I am pretty new to Hibernate based Application Developing.
Recently i run the same code(which is shown in the below) in Eclipse Juno IDE. It works fine.
But when coming to Netbeans it doesn't work.And it shows the error as

> SEVERE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.users users0_ where users0_.uname='username'' at line 1

Here Iam using the Mysql 5.5,IDE-NetBeans-7.2.1.

Here the code i am executing is,

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/office manager?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernatefiles/Users.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hibernating Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Nov 6, 2012 12:42:42 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernatefiles.Users" table="users" catalog="OFFICE MANAGER">
        <id name="uid" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Uid" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="uname" type="string">
            <column name="uname" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="upass" type="string">
            <column name="upass" length="30" />
        </property>
        <property name="ename" type="string">
            <column name="ename" length="100" />
        </property>
        <property name="edesg" type="string">
            <column name="edesg" length="100" />
        </property>
        <property name="contactnumber" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="contactnumber" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Users.java(POJO File)

```
package hibernatefiles;
public class Users  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer uid;
     private String uname;
     private String upass;
     private String ename;
     private String edesg;
     private Integer contactnumber;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String uname, String upass, String ename, String edesg, Integer contactnumber) {
       this.uname = uname;
       this.upass = upass;
       this.ename = ename;
       this.edesg = edesg;
       this.contactnumber = contactnumber;
    }

    public Integer getUid() {
        return this.uid;
    }

    public void setUid(Integer uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
    public String getUname() {
        return this.uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }
    public String getUpass() {
        return this.upass;
    }

    public void setUpass(String upass) {
        this.upass = upass;
    }
    public String getEname() {
        return this.ename;
    }

    public void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }
    public String getEdesg() {
        return this.edesg;
    }

    public void setEdesg(String edesg) {
        this.edesg = edesg;
    }
    public Integer getContactnumber() {
        return this.contactnumber;
    }

    public void setContactnumber(Integer contactnumber) {
        this.contactnumber = contactnumber;
    }

}
```

I am Executing the HQL in the below JSP File by using Query Class.

```
<%@page import="hibernatefiles.Users"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Transaction"%>
<%
    String user_id = request.getParameter("uid");
    String u_pass = request.getParameter("upass");
    out.println("got it dude we get the details..."+user_id+"\n"+u_pass);

    //writing the hibernate code

    Transaction transaction;

    Session ses = hibernatefiles.NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try{
             transaction = ses.beginTransaction();
             String HQL = "FROM Users u WHERE u.uname='"+user_id+"'";
             Query query = ses.createQuery(HQL);
            java.util.List li = query.list();
            Iterator itera = li.iterator();
            while(itera.hasNext()){
        //getting record
                Users u= (Users) itera.next();
        out.println("user name is:"+u.getUname());
                out.println("user password is :"+u.getUpass());         

            }

    }
    catch(Exception error){
        error.printStackTrace();

    }

%>
```

Here NetBeans Log

```
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Office_Manager] is completed
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.5
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : hibernatefiles/Users.hbm.xml
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
INFO: Mapping class: hibernatefiles.Users -> users
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:46 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:46 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:46 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:46 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: autocommit mode: false
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:46 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/office manager?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:46 PM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.5.25a
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.18 ( Revision: tonci.grgin@oracle.com-20110930151701-jfj14ddfq48ifkfq )
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC batch size: 15
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query cache: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createCacheProvider
INFO: Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Echoing all SQL to stdout
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Statistics: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Named query checking : enabled
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:47 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
INFO: building session factory
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:48 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:48 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Nov 06, 2012 2:31:48 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.users users0_ where users0_.uname='manikanta'' at line 1
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
Hibernate: 
    select
        users0_.Uid as Uid0_,
        users0_.uname as uname0_,
        users0_.upass as upass0_,
        users0_.ename as ename0_,
        users0_.edesg as edesg0_,
        users0_.contactnumber as contactn6_0_ 
    from
        OFFICE MANAGER.users users0_ 
    where
        users0_.uname='manikanta'
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.Employers.checking_jsp._jspService(checking_jsp.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.users users0_ where users0_.uname='manikanta'' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Could you add these properties to your Hibernate.cfg.xml? With them, the full query will appear in the log, and we can easily see what's wrong: `<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>` (add them inside the session-factory tag).

Comment: @Pablo thanks for u r reply.I did that.

Comment: change version of mysql connector and try it. http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the schema "OFFICE MANAGER". It has blank space, so it needs to be quoted. Is really "OFFICE MANAGER" the right name? If it is right, then you have to change your hibernate mapping file, to quote the catalog attribute:

```
<class name="hibernatefiles.Users" table="users" catalog="`OFFICE MANAGER`">
```

However, I don't know why it worked in Eclipse. If you are curious, you could try to run it again in eclipse with `<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>` so that is shows the query.

Comment: Thank you.. 
But same code with different data base name (payslip geneartor) worked in eclipse. Is there any reason.Could u please explain that.

Comment: @mani I don't know why. Perhaps a different version of the driver, as hinted by kshitij in his comment?

Comment: I already try that. But it didn't work in netbeans..
And Unfortunately your answer also not solve the problem.The problem is solved when i am replacing space with '_' in netbeans.
But you are answer is work in Eclipse.
And I forgot say the Configuration file in netbeans is auto generated.But in Eclipse it is manually created.
Is there any difference.?

Comment: @mani It worked in eclipse before, right? It should not matter that the configuration is generated manually as long as it's the same configuration. Does the query in netbeans log is the same after changing the hibernate mapping file?